# preg_split mixed HTML and PHP tags except in quotes and comments

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

I have a php page mixed with HTML. Some example code:

```
<?php echo "<p>some text</p>"; ?>/* <? some php in comments ?> */
<p>some HTML text</p> <!-- <h1>some HTML in comments</h1> -->
<? $header_info = <<<END 
\$some="<?php @ob_start(); @session_set_save_handler(); ?>";
END; ?>
<h2>Some more HTML</h2>
```

I would like to split at each PHP and HTML tag but leave any PHP tags or HTML tags in quotes or comments untouched/ignored. This is what I have so far:

```
$array = preg_split("/((^<\?php)|([^'|\"]<\?php)|([^'|\"]<\?)|([^'|\"]\?>)|(<\%)|(\%>))/i", $string, -1);
```

The issue I have is that some of the HTML closing brackets '>' are missing in the final $array. I would like to keep the HTML open and closing tags intact. Sometimes I end up with

```
<p></p instead of <p></p>
```

It should look like this:

```
[0] echo "<p>some text</p>";  
[1] <p>some HTML text</p> 
[2] $header_info = <<<END 
\$some="<?php @ob_start(); @session_set_save_handler(); ?>";
END; 
[3] <h2>Some more HTML</h2>
```

Any comments do not need to be part of the array as long as preg_split does not see them as any delimiters and disregards any of them.

I also just realized that some of the php tags, especially when using eval() can end up like this:

```
"?> <p>some HTML text</p> <?";
```

which would mean that the quotations in my regex would not match any of those cases.

Preg_match() might be a better option, not sure though.

Any help would be very much appreciated as I am not very ingenious when it comes to regex and am rather stuck at this point.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: [THE PONY HE COMES!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) - only here it's worse because you're also trying to parse PHP blocks...

Answer (score 2):

**PREAMBLE**
Since a regular expression solution was asked, the following solution will rely on regular expressions. However, in this particular case, *a PHP parser would be more suited*.

**Regular Expression**

```
#(?<!"|\')<\\?(?:php)?\\s+(.+?)\\?>(?!"|\')|/\*.+\*/|<!--.+-->#is
```

**Scriptlet**

```
$subject = '<?php echo "<p>some text</p>"; ?>/* <? some php in comments ?> */
<p>some HTML text</p> <!-- <h1>some HTML in comments</h1> -->
<? $header_info = <<<END
\\$some="<?php @ob_start(); @session_set_save_handler(); ?>";
END; ?>
<h2>Some more HTML</h2>';

$returnValue = preg_replace('#(?<!"|\')<\\?(?:php)?\\s+(.+?)\\?>(?!"|\')|/\*.+\*/|<!--.+-->#is', '$1', $subject, -1);

var_dump(preg_split('#\\r?\\n#s', $returnValue));
```

**Result**

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(25) "echo "<p>some text</p>"; "
  [1]=>
  string(22) "<p>some HTML text</p> "
  [2]=>
  string(21) "$header_info = <<<END"
  [3]=>
  string(60) "\$some="<?php @ob_start(); @session_set_save_handler(); ?>";"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "END; "
  [5]=>
  string(23) "<h2>Some more HTML</h2>"
}
```

**DEMO**
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/017a51877b50f272f151feade7b59e142757481e

**Discussion**

```
1. # 
2. (?<!"|\')
3. <\\?(?:php)?\\s+
4. (.+?)
5. \\?>
6. (?!"|\')
7. |/\*.+\*/
8. |<!--.+-->
9. #is
```

**line 1** I use this regex delimiter since it permits avoiding the escape of /
**line 2** Here is the *key* of the regex. A **negative lookbehind** is used to ensure that the next opening php tag is NOT preceded by any single or double quote.
**line 3** Here is defined what an opening php tag is. To support ASP tags too, this line can be changed like this : `<\\?(?:php|%)?\\s+`
**line 4** Since we have detected the start of a php code sequence, we match any char appeaing in this php code sequence. Note on **line 9** we use the `s` flag to indicate that we want new lines as well in php code sequence.
**line 5** We mark the end of php code sequence.
**line 6** We ensure that the preceding matched php tag is not followed by any single/double quote with the **negative lookahead** assertion.
**line 7,8** If we find some php/HTML comment, they will be simply ignored.
**line 9** End f regex.

**Known issues**

- After executing the regex on `$subject`, the lines are simply splitted with a newline (preceded by an optional carriage return) delimiter.
- No effort is made to handle php heredoc or newdoc syntaxes.
- This regex should **NOT** be viewed as a bulletproof regex against any php code in the wild. PHP parsers are far more suited.

Comment: Thanks very much Stephan for your very detailed answer. I forgot to mention that it is crucial to handle any type of php code input. I wonder if anyone could outline an example using the tokenizer. Thanks in advance.


I am not very familiar with the Tokenizer. I did some research and found some code on how to strip comments from PHP using the PHP Tokenizer but have a hard time understanding the code.

Comment: Your code should output the following instead:
    <pre><code>
    [0]=>$subject = '<?php echo "<p>some text</p>"; ?>'; /* <? some php in comments ?> */
    [1]=><p>some HTML text</p> <!-- <h1>some HTML in comments</h1> -->
    [2]=>$header_info = <<<END \\$some="<?php @ob_start(); @session_set_save_handler(); ?>";
END; ?>
    [3]="<h2>Some more HTML</h2> "</code></pre> 

<p>So basically I would like to split at every php tag that is not in quotes or within comments and any HTML in between ends up in its own array key. Loosing or keeping comments intact is not relevant.</p>

Comment: sorry I tried to format the above code but it got all jumbled. This is my first post. Read through comment formatting but...

Comment: @user1862374 I wasn't able to understand how the code should be outputted. Can you paste it again in your question as an update ? Tks